# IVR on GUI Trixbox (Query)

Tags: asterisk, trixbox

I am very new to this technology and i am trying to create an IVR on trixbox. i have installed trixbox on vmware, my question is this how can i create a menu (IVR) and sub menu in trixbox... in GUI of the trixbox!
More over i have installed the VMware and virtually created a trixbox stuff in my machince! it is working fine in the command based interface! but as far as GUI interface is concerned it really does not work with its own provided IP address in the browser!!! kindly also let me about the trixbox tutorials which can implement the IVR menus and sub menus for phone operations...

Answer (score 2):

Trixbox use Freepbx gui

here is one of tutorial

http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/administration-guide/creating-an-ivr